# What is this Thai tea, spiral plant-part?

Tags: tea, thai-cuisine

I bought these, for me, nicely spiral looking dried fruits(?) in a tea-specialized shop in Bangkok in the area of the bridge leading from Phra Khanong towards On Nut (pictured below a cooked product).

I made a gentle tasting tea from these before bed time ; it was very nice for me.

What is this Thai tea, spiral plant-part?

Please share some information you find crucial about it in the answer.

[image]

Comment: I suspect that these are flower buds. Possibly from a Convolvulus (morning glory) species, but I'm certainly no expert on teas or on plants that grow in/around Thailand. Open one up and see what's inside, it might help.

Comment: I'm getting a real H. R. Giger vibe from that picture.

Comment: @Sneftel I'm glad I [Googled that](https://www.google.com/search?q=H.+R.+Giger&sxsrf=ACYBGNQxZScTtLC2VTQxTLunLFaxYQOAHQ:1581841199059&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwie8orW0dXnAhWLvp4KHbePCyoQ_AUoAXoECBcQAw&biw=1707&bih=804&dpr=1.13)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are fruits of the East Indian screw tree (*[Helicteres isora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicteres_isora)*). The plants are native to Asia and Australia and its fruits are used in folk medicine.

Comment: Hi byrdzeye, your answer cannot be allowed to stand if it contains medical claims. They have to be edited out, or the answer has to be deleted. You can change other parts of the content, if they are not in your sense, but please don't list what diseases it is used for.